# Binomial coefficients in discrete valuation rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-analysis

Let $V$ be a complete discrete valuation ring whose residue field is a finite field $k=\mathbf{F}_q$. Let $\pi\in V$ be a uniformizer.

For any integer $d,n\ge 0$, define:

$${\pi^d \choose n} := \frac{\pi^d\cdot(\pi^d -1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(\pi^d-n+1)}{n!}.$$

> - Is ${\pi^d\choose n}$ an element of $V$?
> - For exactly what integers $n\ge 0$ is ${\pi^d\choose n}$ a unit?

**Example.** If $V = \mathbf{Z}_p$, $\pi = p$, then ${p^d\choose n}$ is zero unless $0\le n\le p^d$, and its $p$-adic valuation is $d-v_p(n)\ge 0$ for $1\le n\le p^d$. In all cases, the answer to the first question is yes, and the answer to the second question is: for $n = 0, c\cdot p^d$, with $(c,p) = 1$.

Comment: If you don't stick to uniformizers there is a problem in every finite extension $K$ of $\mathbf Q_p$ whose residue field is bigger than $\mathbf F_p$: if $\alpha \in \mathcal O_K$ and its reduction in the residue field is outside $\mathbf F_p$ then $|\alpha - k|_p = 1$ for every $k \in \mathbf Z$, so $|\binom{\alpha}{n}|_p = |1/n!|_p > 1$ when $n \geq p$.

Comment: @KConrad I agree. In my question, I do stick to uniformizers. I wonder if, when $K := \text{Frac}(V) / \mathbf{Q}_p$ is a finite unramified extension, the problem in the answer, disappears, and my questions have positive answer.

Comment: No, it still doesn't work. Let $K$ be the unramified quadratic extension of $\mathbf{Q}_2$ and let $\pi = 2\alpha$ where $\alpha \bmod 2$ is not in $\mathbf{F}_2$. Then the valuation of $\binom{\pi}{4}$ is $-1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $p=2=n$, $d=1$, $V=\mathbf{Z}_2[\sqrt{2}]$ and $\pi=\sqrt{2}$, then
$$ \binom{\pi^d}{n} = \frac{\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{2} - 1)}{2} = 2^{-1/2}\cdot \mathrm{unit} \notin V. $$